# UITabBarController icons and tint not showing for a while

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I have an application with two storyboards. One for login stuff and the other one for the rest of the application. The second one is loaded when the user logs in (via a `NSNotification` observer), using `[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController]` to get the first controller, which is a `UITabBarController` and I set it as the `rootViewController` (all of this in the application delegate).

The problem only happens when the user logs in for the first time. The tab bar doesn't show a background (unless I set one, but it appears as a solid color instead of the tinted default style), and it doesn't show the tab bar icons, except for the one that is selected. After a few seconds, it refreshes and shows all icons and tinted background.

There's no other code in the application modifying the tab bar, except for its own controller which updates the badges when a notification is received. The time it takes to automatically refresh varies, sometimes it takes about 2 seconds, and other times it won't update unless you select each of the (five) tabs. To reproduce this, I need to uninstall the app each time, because after the first use, the tab bar behaves normally. Icons are set within the storyboard file and are not updated anywhere programatically.

Here's a screenshot of the tab bar as it shows the first time:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqT5X.png

And this is how it looks (and should) after a while:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y8ch.png

*Edit: Added some of the loading code*

This is the code that loads both storyboards:

```
- (void)showInterface {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard;
    UIViewController *viewController;
    if ([[self.configuration userManager] userIsLoggedIn]) {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:MAIN_STORYBOARD_NAME bundle:nil];
        CWNTabBarController *tabController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        tabController.configuration = self.configuration;
        self.configuration.notificationDisplay = tabController;
        viewController = tabController;
    }
    else {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:WELCOME_STORYBOARD_NAME bundle:nil];
        CWNWelcomeController *welcomeController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        welcomeController.configuration = self.configuration;
        viewController = welcomeController;
    }

    [self.window performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setRootViewController:) withObject:viewController waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Above code is called in `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` using:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self showInterface];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to use one storyboard and modify the tabbar's viewcontrollers later.NSMutableArray * vcs = [NSMutableArray 
                                arrayWithArray:[self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
 [vcs removeObjectAtIndex:2];
 [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:vcs];

Comment: Show some code. This kind of issue sounds like a possible threading problem...

Comment: Thanks for your interest! I just updated the question.

Comment: I have run into the same problem. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and my problem was that I needed to launch the other view controller in the main thread:

```
if response.statusCode == 200 {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! SpoktTabBarController
     self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   })
}
```